# Google Apps Script Bad Value

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm getting a "bad value on line 4"... I don't know why. I'm trying to make a Google sheet that automatically opens to an assigned tab based on gmail address for a large team. Please help!

```
function onOpen() {
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var username = email.slice(0,-9);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(username);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect here your issue is a misunderstanding of the function '[.openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))'.

This function is designed so that you identify and open the spreadsheet using a spreadsheet ID (The alphanumeric part of the URL when opening a sheet, such as "abc1234567"). From context and your use of the variable 'username', I think that instead you're somehow trying to open it based on an email ID (Such as user@domain.com).

Incidentally, you won't be able to open the sheet in an assigned tab using Scripts. That's not what it does, and it's unable to manipulate a users browser. Perhaps an [extension for Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) would be closer to what you're looking for.